# "Invalid cross-thread access" when changing a WP8 textBlock

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm coming from VB 6 and am semi-new to VB.NET.
I'm writing a Windows Phone 8 application. There's a grid in which I have several textBlocks that I want to dynamically display data from a file stream (that contains scanned data).

When the WP8 page opens, it automatically loads the data into the textBlocks. This works. Before I load the data from the file, I want to "reset" all textBlocks and hide them. For this I wanted to use a procedure which essentially does the following for every textBlock:

```
tbl1.Text = ""
tbl1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
```

This works exactly one time: when the page loads. The procedure does not produce an error.

Now when I call that method again later, when I want to refresh the data shown on the page, I get the following error on the first line of code shown above:

**An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access.**

I'm a bit lost now. In VB6 I was able to do whatever I wanted with my UI elements. I presume I'm making some kind of newbie mistake here?

I read somewhere about some Dispatcher thing. But that seems overly complicated to simply change a value in a textBlock to me. Is there no simple way?

Comment: What method you use to change this values? Is it run asynchronously? Can you show more code coneccted with that method?

Comment: The first time it's called in the constructor of the page. But not directly. It's in a non-async sub procedure.
The second time it's called in an event after the scanner received data: Private Sub oBCScanner_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs)

Comment: As I've understood first time it works (when the page loads). So where do you invoke it for the second time? Some build-in methonds can also be run asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick help! I have much to learn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is indeed to use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    tbl1.Text = ""
    tbl1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
});
```

The reason why you need this is because you try to access an object that depends on the UI thread from a non-UI thread.

Comment: This works. (also thanks to the other similar answer!)

I was able to do this, using the c# code above in vb.net format. I had to use this Dispatcher on the sub procedure, that is responsible for loading the file data into the UI:
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() mLoadScannerData())

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are not calling the method from UI thread. Try using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke:

```cs
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
    {
        tbl1.Text = "";
        tbl1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    });
```